Comparing Screenshot images with OpenCV & C# .NET
I have been working on a solution that aims to improve our companies screenshot comparison. Currently, we are seeing lots of failures due to pixel differences etc. I have implemented a solution in OpenCvSharp that is 90% working. However, certain images seem to give false positives, drawing contours (red boxes) around things that have not changed. This seems to be somewhat random and not linked to any particular image type. Please see the below images for the details (Ignore the boxes in the top left and right corners, I have done this to hide specific company details)
Baseline file:

Diff file (After comparison has been executed) see the small red box around the graph data:

This work aims to avoid issues like below, but after nearly two weeks of development and tweaking the code, I am starting to run out of ideas. The code I am currently using is below, with the below parameters:
 1. baselinePath -> This is simply the path to the baseline image
 2. currentImageScreenshot - The current screenshot to compare against baseline
 3. testName -> string containing a test name for debugging and logging purposes
 4. imageConfig -> Object containing threshold values
  
  public static void CompareImagesForDifferences(string baselineImagePath, Screenshot currentImageScreenshot, string testName, ImageComparisonConfig imageConfig)
  {
         string currentImagePath =  SaveCurrentImage(currentImageScreenshot, testName, imageConfig);
         Mat baselineImage = LoadImage(baselineImagePath);
         Mat currentImage = LoadImage(currentImagePath);
    
         ResizeImage(baselineImage, currentImage);
    
         Mat baselineGray = ConvertToGrayscale(baselineImage);
         Mat currentGray = ConvertToGrayscale(currentImage);
    
         double ssimScore = ComputeSSIM(baselineGray, currentGray, out Mat ssimMap);
    
         if (ssimScore >= double.Parse(imageConfig.GetSSIMThresholdSetting()))
         {
            // Images are identical
            Logger.Info("Images are similar. No significant differences detected.");
            return;
         }
    
         if (isSignificantChangesBetweenImages(baselineImage, currentImage, ssimMap, imageConfig, out Mat filledImage))
         {
            string diffImagePath = $@"{imageConfig.GetFailuresPath()}\\{testName}_Diff.png";
            SaveDiffImage(filledImage, testName, imageConfig, diffImagePath, baselineImagePath);
         }
      }

The code below is where the issue lies. This is where the differences are calculated. The method takes 2 Mat objects containing baseline and new image, aswell as the ssimMap and config.
private static bool isSignificantChangesBetweenImages(Mat baselineImage, Mat currentImage, Mat ssimMap, ImageComparisonConfig imageConfig, out Mat filledImage)
{
   filledImage = currentImage.Clone();
   Mat diff = new Mat();
   ssimMap.ConvertTo(diff, MatType.CV_8UC1, 255);

   Mat thresh = new Mat();
   Cv2.Threshold(diff, thresh, 0, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv | ThresholdTypes.Otsu);

   Point[][] contourDifferencePoints;
   HierarchyIndex[] hierarchyIndex;
   Cv2.FindContours(thresh, out contourDifferencePoints, out hierarchyIndex, RetrievalModes.List, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);

   return DrawSignificantChanges(baselineImage, contourDifferencePoints, imageConfig, filledImage);
}

The below method will then draw the contour points (if any). I believe that something within this code is what is creating the false positives. I have added some code in here to ignore any changes around the image border, as generally there would be no changes around the border for this particular application. Currently the imageConfig.GetPixelToleranceSetting() is set to 10. My next guess would be to up this number to either 15 or 20
private static bool DrawSignificantChanges(Mat baselineImage, Point[][] contours, ImageComparisonConfig imageConfig, Mat filledImage, double minAreaRatio = 0.0001, double maxAreaRatio = 0.1)
{
   bool hasSignificantChanges = false;
   double totalImageArea = baselineImage.Width * baselineImage.Height;
   double minArea = totalImageArea * minAreaRatio;
   double maxArea = totalImageArea * maxAreaRatio;

   foreach (var contour in contours)
   {
      double area = Cv2.ContourArea(contour);
      if (area < minArea || area > maxArea) continue;

      Rect boundingRect = Cv2.BoundingRect(contour);

      // Ignore changes near the image border
      int borderThreshold = 5;
      if (boundingRect.X <= borderThreshold || boundingRect.Y <= borderThreshold ||
          boundingRect.X + boundingRect.Width >= baselineImage.Width - borderThreshold ||
          boundingRect.Y + boundingRect.Height >= baselineImage.Height - borderThreshold)
      {
         continue;
      }

      // Check if the difference is significant enough
      using (Mat roi = new Mat(baselineImage, boundingRect))
      {
         Scalar mean = Cv2.Mean(roi);
         if (mean.Val0 < int.Parse(imageConfig.GetPixelToleranceSetting())) // Adjust this threshold as needed
         {
            continue;
         }
      }

      // Draw Rectangle shape in red around the differences
      Cv2.Rectangle(filledImage, boundingRect, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
      hasSignificantChanges = true;
   }
   return hasSignificantChanges;
}

Lastly, the ComputeSSIM method (I have taken this from a post written in python and converted to CSharp)
 public static double StructuralSimilarityIndex(Mat img1, Mat img2, out Mat diff)
  {
     const double K1 = 0.01;
     const double K2 = 0.03;
     const double L = 255;

     // Constants for SSIM calculation
     double c1 = Math.Pow(K1 * L, 2);
     double c2 = Math.Pow(K2 * L, 2);

     // Convert images to floating point
     using var f1 = new Mat();
     using var f2 = new Mat();
     img1.ConvertTo(f1, MatType.CV_32F);
     img2.ConvertTo(f2, MatType.CV_32F);

     // Compute means
     using var mu1 = new Mat();
     using var mu2 = new Mat();
     Cv2.GaussianBlur(f1, mu1, new Size(11, 11), 1.5);
     Cv2.GaussianBlur(f2, mu2, new Size(11, 11), 1.5);

     // Compute squares
     using var mu1Sq = mu1.Mul(mu1);
     using var mu2Sq = mu2.Mul(mu2);
     using var mu1Mu2 = mu1.Mul(mu2);

     // Compute variances and covariance
     using var temp1 = new Mat();
     using var temp2 = new Mat();
     using var sigma1Sq = new Mat();
     using var sigma2Sq = new Mat();
     using var sigma12 = new Mat();

     Cv2.GaussianBlur(f1.Mul(f1), temp1, new Size(11, 11), 1.5);
     Cv2.GaussianBlur(f2.Mul(f2), temp2, new Size(11, 11), 1.5);

     Cv2.Subtract(temp1, mu1Sq, sigma1Sq);
     Cv2.Subtract(temp2, mu2Sq, sigma2Sq);

     Cv2.GaussianBlur(f1.Mul(f2), sigma12, new Size(11, 11), 1.5);
     Cv2.Subtract(sigma12, mu1Mu2, sigma12);

     // Compute SSIM
     using var numerator1 = new Mat();
     using var numerator2 = new Mat();
     using var denominator1 = new Mat();
     using var denominator2 = new Mat();

     Cv2.Multiply(mu1Mu2, 2, numerator1);
     Cv2.Add(numerator1, Scalar.All(c1), numerator1);

     Cv2.Multiply(sigma12, 2, numerator2);
     Cv2.Add(numerator2, Scalar.All(c2), numerator2);

     Cv2.Add(mu1Sq, mu2Sq, denominator1);
     Cv2.Add(denominator1, Scalar.All(c1), denominator1);

     Cv2.Add(sigma1Sq, sigma2Sq, denominator2);
     Cv2.Add(denominator2, Scalar.All(c2), denominator2);

     using var ssimMap = new Mat();
     using var temp = new Mat();

     Cv2.Multiply(numerator1, numerator2, temp);
     Cv2.Multiply(denominator1, denominator2, ssimMap);
     Cv2.Divide(temp, ssimMap, ssimMap);

     // Calculate mean SSIM
     var mssim = Cv2.Mean(ssimMap);

     // Calculate difference map for visualization
     diff = new Mat();
     Cv2.Absdiff(img1, img2, diff);
     Cv2.Normalize(diff, diff, 0, 255, NormTypes.MinMax);
     diff.ConvertTo(diff, MatType.CV_8UC1);

     return mssim.Val0;
  }


[mre] please. that also covers input data. you can leave your illustrations in the post, but input data is vital.

I have edited the post to reflect the input parameters and make it more concise

How are the images sourced? How does the threshold image look? What kind of difference are you looking for? What kind of differences do you want to ignore? The choice of Otsu thresholding seem odd. If you want to ignore small differences, like compression artifacts, you probably do not want an adaptive threshold. You probably want to inspect the threshold image and see if it looks as you expect, and adjust parameters if not.

Images are created through Selenium. A baseline image is created via a screenshot in the selenium framework. We then run against the baseline, again taking a screenshot with selenium and comparing that the new image is equal to the original baselined image. I only want to ignore changes that would not be detected by the human eye (pixel differences). If there are any changes to the metadata or structure of the image, then it needs to be flagged as a change. i.e - Graph figure changes from 35% to 36% or a particular element has been removed from the page in the latest image.
